# igraph - generating random graph based on degree sequence

Tags: random, igraph

I am following page 80 in Kolaczyk and Csardi's book "Statistical Analysis of Network Data with R",,, and trying to generate a random graph based on a degree sequence.

I get an error message saying: "Error in match.arg".

Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include a (portion) of the code

Comment: If you don't need have to use igraph, you could play with Python NetworkX and use: `nx.expected_degree_graph(degree_sequence)`